# Is it also clear to say "The main diagonal of a matrix is the collection of entries that run from the top left to bottom right"?

Tags: meaning

This [post](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vmch13/vmch13_17.html) says

> The main diagonal of a matrix consists of those elements that lie on the diagonal that runs from top left to bottom right.

Is it also clear when I rewrite that as

"The main diagonal of a matrix is the collection of entries that run from the top left to bottom right"?

Actually, the "collection of entries" is adapted from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal)

Comment: That would be a matter of opinion. I personally find addition of redundant words makes things less clear. So, the original sentence is clearer. What are you adding by saying "collection of"?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically a "collection" is not ordered, so by using that word a reader might infer that the position of each element along the diagonal is not important. For a general description the original is better. If you are going to treat the main diagonal as a mathematical object you would need more precision in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, sure.  You can rewrite it as what you suggest.

Academically, no, you cannot interchange words in that way.  As you get into a discipline, you have to use very controlled terminology.  Synonyms for words may have a slightly nuanced and different meaning.

In math, a collection is a set of distinct objects.  I have never seen elements of a matrix referred to as a collection, and I would **you cannot call the elements in the main diagonal a collection**.  I have, however, seen a group of rows or columns referred to as a collection.

Entries can be used to describe a matrix's elements, but "elements" is more common.

Comment: Right, but elements are not a *collection* of entries, right? In other words, elements or entries but not collection. The original does not say a set or collection.

Comment: Actually, the "collection of entries" is adapted from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal)

Comment: It may be "adapted from Wikipedia" but you adapted it by changing the words! Not great. Wikipedia calls it a "list of entries".